# Arithmetic operation when multiple textbox is created by js

Tags: javascript, php

I created a basic table where textboxes are available on button click. Now I want to perform some arithmetic operations on it and show value in the total column and parallelly I want to to do the mass calculation at the end. `(quantity * price = total)` in each row and at the end for the table

What I want:

```
         Quantity       Price       Total
          28             300         8400
           8              50          400
TOTAL     36             350         8800
```

I use this JS code to create multiple textbox:

```js
var index = 1;

function insertRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("rep1");
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var t1 = document.createElement("input");
    t1.id = "quan" + index;
    t1.name = "quan[]";
    cell1.appendChild(t1).classList.add('form-control');

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var t2 = document.createElement("input");
    t2.id = "price" + index;
    t2.name = "price[]";
    cell2.appendChild(t2).classList.add('form-control');

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var t3 = document.createElement("input");
    t3.id = "total" + index;
    t3.name = "total[]";
    cell3.appendChild(t3).classList.add('form-control');

    index++;
}
```

This for html (For holding total of Quantity,Price,Total):

```html
Quantity Total<input type="number" name="quanTotal" readonly>
Price Total<input type="number" name="priceTotal" readonly>
Grand Total<input type="number" name="grandTotal" readonly>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? post it here.

Comment: Show us your HTML

Comment: other then this no HTML belongs to this code Because I created textboxes using js. That's why I am not able to calculate the result for multiple textboxes if they created dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the code.And when you click the add row button it will perform the arithmetic operation and total will be appending the total field textboxes. Hope this is what you want.

```js
$(function(){
insertRow();
$('#addrow').on('click',function(){
insertRow();
});
//var index = 1;

function insertRow() {
    var index = $('#noofrows').val();
    var table = document.getElementById("rep1");
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var t1 = document.createElement("input");
    t1.id = "quan" + index;
    t1.name = "quan[]";
    cell1.appendChild(t1).classList.add('form-control');

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var t2 = document.createElement("input");
    t2.id = "price" + index;
    t2.name = "price[]";
    cell2.appendChild(t2).classList.add('form-control');

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var t3 = document.createElement("input");
    t3.id = "total" + index;
    t3.name = "total[]";
    cell3.appendChild(t3).classList.add('form-control');

    index++;
    $('#noofrows').val(index);
    
    var quan = $('input[name="quan[]"]').map(function () {
    return (this.value)?this.value:'0'; 
    }).get();
    //console.log(quan);
    quan_total=0;
    for(i=0;i<quan.length;i++){
     quan_total += parseInt(quan[i]);
    }
    $('[name=quanTotal]').val(quan_total);
    
    var price = $('input[name="price[]"]').map(function () {
    return (this.value)?this.value:'0'; 
    }).get();
    price_total=0;
    for(i=0;i<price.length;i++){
     price_total += parseInt(price[i]);
     j=i+1;
     t =parseInt(price[i])+parseInt(quan[i]);
     $('#total'+j).val(t);
    }
    $('[name=priceTotal]').val(price_total);
    
    var grand = $('input[name="total[]"]').map(function () {
    return (this.value)?this.value:'0'; 
    }).get();
    grand_total=0;
    for(i=0;i<grand.length;i++){
     grand_total += parseInt(grand[i]);
    }
    $('[name=grandTotal]').val(grand_total);
}


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rep1">
<input type='button' name='addrow' id='addrow' value='Add Row'>
</table>

Quantity Total<input type="number" name="quanTotal" readonly>
Price Total<input type="number" name="priceTotal" readonly>
Grand Total<input type="number" name="grandTotal" readonly>
<input type='hidden' name='noofrows'  id='noofrows' value='1'>
```

Comment: Glad to receive such a fine help but i also want to calculate result of 1 textbox and 2 textbox and show anser in third. like quantity * price = total